# How to pass specific links through LinkedIn Share Article?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, linkedin-api

When clicking on the LinkedIn button, the whole link doesn't get passed when the picture is clicked, however the facebook link works completely fine.
The linkedIn also used to work but not anymore, has anything changed since then?

```
            <div align="center">
              <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={"https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2FmyCompany.com%2Fanbefal%3Fcompany%3D" + encodeURI(this.state.company) + "%26token%3D" + this.state.token + "&amp;src=sdkpreparse"} className="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><img alt="Share Facebook" style={{ width: '40px', marginRight: '50px' }} src={require('../static/img/icons/facebook.png')} /></a>
              <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={"https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3A%2F%2FmyCompany.com%2Fanbefal%3Fcompany%3D" + encodeURI(this.state.company) + "%26token%3D" + encodeURI(this.state.token) + "&amp;src=sdkpreparse"} className="a2a_button_linkedin_share"><img alt="Share LinkedIn" style={{ width: '40px' }} src={require('../static/img/icons/linkedin.png')} /></a>
            </div>
            <br />
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

*That is just a preview that you are seeing.  The full URLs still do fully display -- **but only once they shared.***

You can still pass specific links (i.e., not just a domain) to LinkedIn.  It seems, though, that the *preview* for the link is what is showing just the domain, instead of the full URL.  It's just a preview, though:

[image]

But now look at the LinkedIn conversation, *after I have shared the URL*...

[image]

See!  **Even though the preview only lists example.com, the actual sharing will show `example.com/Your/Full/Specific/Page.html`.**